# OpenCV - How to mask match picture in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to match pictures from my a.jpg and b.jpg.

But there is some of that area I don't want to match.

How should I mask it?

(PS: If transfer these area to black, it will effect `cv2.matchTemplate`)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread("a.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("b.jpg")
myROI = img2[183:374,293:408]
# here I want to mask a part of myROI .. 
# It means that I don't want to match something in my picture...
# How should I do ?
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img1,myROI,method= eval('cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED'))

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
print max_val*100 # score
```

a.jpg
[image]

b.jpg

[image]

Comment: can you upload the two images as well

Comment: @JeruLuke , edit !

Comment: first try `cv2.matchTemplate()` and then perform masking

Comment: @JeruLuke , I got it  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread("a.jpg")
img2 = cv2.imread("b.jpg")
mymask = cv2.imread("mask.jpg") # mask shape must = template

#  mask only run in method = CV_TM_SQDIFF and CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED.
me= eval('cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED')

res1 = cv2.matchTemplate(img1,img2,method= me, mask = mymask)
res2 = cv2.matchTemplate(img1,img2,method= eval('cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED'))

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res1)
print max_val*100 # score 1 -> 62

min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res2)
print max_val*100 # score 2 -> 99
```

---

a https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsqA9.jpg

b https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BemF.jpg

mask https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2DZI.jpg